# laravel base path

Tags: php, laravel

Im using URL::base(); and I get this URL:

```
http://www.kp.com.mx/sis_colgate/public
```

but what I need is this complete path:

```
/home/belendez/public_html/sis_colgate/public
```

Does anybody knows how can I get that path?
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want to use is the `path` helper.

The URL helper is for generating HTTP URLs.

Try the `path('public')` function in Laravel 3,

or the `public_path()` function in Laravel 4.

Edit: Updated with answer for Laravel 4, thanks Erin

Comment: Note that this is the Laravel 3 answer, Laravel 4 has a public_path() function instead

Answer (score 31):

Laravel has [helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#paths) for paths:

```
base_path();    // '/var/www/mysite'
app_path();     // '/var/www/mysite/app'
storage_path(); // '/var/www/mysite/storage'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can find info about paths in documentation:

- [Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#paths)
- [Laravel 5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths)
- [Laravel 4](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths)