# change base_path() to public html in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload file in my website ,but when i upload the file isn't enter to folder public html ,

```
$resorce->move(\base_path() ."public/homepage", $name);
```

how to change this ?

in shared hosting, i am using laravel 7

Comment: 1) see the "paths" section of https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers, 2) drop that `\\`  in front of your first param

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel base path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631436/laravel-base-path)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the helper method public_path() defined [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-public-path) instead of base_path().

Also not sure if this is a direct copy/paste so I just wanted to point out that there is a typo so I've updated the call below.

```
$resource->move(public_path().'homepage');
```