# Laravel 10 Facades\Process does not recognize command due to missing system path

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade

I'm writing a middleware in Laravel 10 to grab the git version of my app. I'm developing on Windows 11 using VSCode. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Process;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AppVersion
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {   
        $label = "V";
        $version = "0.1.0";

        // Get version string from git
        $hash = Process::run('git log --pretty="%h" -n1 HEAD')->output();
        $date = Process::run('git log -n1 --pretty=%ci HEAD')->output();

        $version_string = "test";
        config(['app.version' => $version_string]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

However, in the `->errorOutput()` I get the message:

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

The `Process::run` is working with basic commands like `DIR` and git is installed on my system and callable in a terminal, i.e. the PATH is set to the git executable. Thus, I was suspecting that Process::run is not using my system PATH variable to find the command. To check this, I did run

```
dd(Process::run("path")->output());
```

and received the output:

> "PATH=(null)"

According my understanding, the system path should be used to find commands, but it is not. What am I missing here? Do I have to manually add %PATH% somewhere in Laravel?

Comment: you need to `cd` to`base_path`. Check this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266349

Comment: change `Process::run('git log` to `Process::run('cd '+base_path()+' && git log`

Comment: You might want to run `Process::run('pwd');` just to check you are at the correct path where the `.git` folder is located

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Correct, I need to change to base_bath first. However, this does not solve my problem, as the problem still is that the system path is not used to find the command and thus, git is not recognized as a command.

Comment: Did you check the pwd? Is it the correct path where you usually do git commands? In bash, can you run git commands ?

Comment: Yes, path is correct and I can run git commands in the Windows command terminal (cmd not bash). My problem is, that Process::run does not find git, because the Windows %PATH% is not passed to Process::run.

Comment: weird suggestion but try double quotes [**""**] or backticks [**``**] instead of single quotes [**''**]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Since the PATH is not included in the search path, I added the full path to git. It's not the nicest solution and I would be happy to learn if there is a better way to do this.

Here is how I do it:

```
        $git_commands = [
            "\"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git\"",
            "/bin/git",
            "/var/packages/Git/target/bin/git"
        ];
        
        foreach($git_commands as $git_command) {
            // Get version string from git
            if(shell_exec("$git_command -v") !== null) {
                $hash = Process::path(base_path())->run("$git_command log -n1 --pretty=%h  HEAD")->output();
                $date = Process::path(base_path())->run("$git_command log -n1 --pretty=%ci HEAD")->output();
                break;
            }
        }
```